# Python3 Remove \n from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, replace

Helle @all!

I trying to remove \n characters from a list it looks like this:
tryed a for loop:

```
for hotel in hotel_url_list:
    hotel.replace('\n', '')
```

it doesn't work!
phyton3 prints:

```
['\n/hotel/at/alpen-adria-stadthotel.de.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaA6IAQGYAQfCAQp3aW5kb3dzIDEwyAEM2AEB6AEB-AELkgIBeagCAw;\n/sid=e812ccd62b87bc158a2175bdc410f874;ucfs=1;]
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

`str.replace` does not mutate the string (in fact, strings are immutable) but returns a new string. Therefore

```
hotel.replace('\n', '')
```

produces a new string which you immediately throw away because you don't have any reference to it.

An easy way to get what you want is to build a new list and reassign the name `hotel_url_list`.

```
hotel_url_list = [hotel.replace('\n', '') for hotel in hotel_url_list]
```

Comment: @ timgeb: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Mr.Elfman No problem. If the question is solved then please consider accepting my answer by clicking the green checkmark next to it.